# И они же - приударяют

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Пока писал предыдущий вопрос, возник следующий: за девушками они *приударяют*. И вот интересно, почему именно приударяют? Откуда это слово?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Приударить - это начать быстро и энергично действовать (прямое значение слова): Гребцы приударили в вёсла. Ансамбль приударил ещё(стали играть громче или быстрее).

Другое значение - неожиданно или с силой начаться (о дожде, морозе ). Приударил ливень. Ночью приударил морозец.

И наконец  можно начать ухаживать за женщиной и приударить (в переносном значении)не шутя.